# How to match any integer in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

To match any string from table , I use `Restrictions.like("fieldname","%")` . How do I achieve the same when the matching field is an integer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Restrictions has many methods like eq, ge,gt,le, lt, in
```

You can use any one from above depending on contition to check.

[Refer API doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html)

Comment: @user2067771 consider accepting answer and upvoting all who help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict to a specific integer value, use `Restrictions.eq(...)` as described by the other Answers.  You can also do other simple relations; e.g. not equal, less than, and so on.

If you want to "restrict" an integer field to have *any* integer value (not a specific value), the restriction is no-op.

If you want to restrict a string field to consist of digits, then you will probably need to resort to using `Restrictions.sqlRestriction(...)`, and a database-specific constraint (e.g. using regular expressions, if the database supports this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
Restrictions.eq("integerId", integerIdValue));
```

where `integerIdValue` is of type Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
Restrictions.eq("intValue", 10000)
```

For more information [visit](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing).

Comment: Won't that just match the field with value exactly the same as 10000?

Comment: No i didn't. Read the title.